# Laravel: How to define belongsTo in a MorphPivot?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphism, belongs-to, eloquent-relationship

In my project there is a Many-to-Many polymorphic relationship (Many instances of a model called Package (morphedByMany) can contain many different content types (each MorphedToMany).

I've created a pivot table containing some additional fields that I'll need to access and query by, and so I've decided that the best thing would be to create a Pivot model by extending the MorphPivot.

Querying is now easy enough, however, I can't access the content through a relation (which I can do if i query the App\Packages::findOrFail(1)->contentType()). I know I should declare that the pivot belongsTo the contentType, but I'm not sure how to go about it seeing as it could belong to any of the morphed contentTypes.

**EDIT**
**Code blocks as requested**

Content1

```
class Song extends Model
{

  public function packages()
  {
      return $this->morphToMany('App\Package', 'packageable')->withPivot('choice')->using('App\PackageContent');
  }
```

Content2

```
class Video extends Model
{

  public function packages()
  {
      return $this->morphToMany('App\Package', 'packageable')->withPivot('choice')->using('App\PackageContent');
  }
```

Package

```
class Package extends Model
{
  public function songs()
  {
      return $this->morphedByMany('App\Song', 'packageable')->withPivot('choice')->using('App\PackageContent');
  }

  public function videos()
  {
      return $this->morphedByMany('App\Video', 'packageable')->withPivot('choice')->using('App\PackageContent');
  }
```

MorphPivot

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphPivot;

class PackageContent extends MorphPivot
{
  protected $table = 'packageables';
```

Pivot table migration

```
    public function up()
    {
      Schema::create('packageables', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('package_id');
        $table->integer('packageable_id');
        $table->string('packageable_type');
        $table->integer('choice');
      });
    }
```

Comment: Please post the relationships, the pivot model and the pivot table migration.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a couple of years, but maybe someone stumbles here. I had the same problem and solved it like this:

```php
class PackageContent extends MorphPivot
{
  protected $table = 'packageables';

  public function package()
  {
    // regular belongs to
    return $this->belongsTo(Package::class); 
  }

  public function packageable()
  {
    // one to one morph, can also be named different
    return $this->morphTo(); 
  }
}
```